# Htacces wildcard subdomain problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

Hello I have a problem with wildcard subdomains with htaccess and mod_rewrite.

I want www.domain.com/index.php?foo=x&bar=y translated to x-y.domain.com

My htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)-(.*?).domain.com$

RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?foo=%1&bar=%2
```

This work but with one minor issue, if I go to x-y.domain.com. Its show www.domain.com, but if I go to x-y.domain.com/z ( 'z' can be every value, even 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf' ) it shows the right page, my application doesnt use z for anything its just there for no reason, but its necessary to show the right page.

**Solution**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)-(.*?).domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)    index.php?foo=%1&bar=%2 [NC]
```

I dont know why it works but it works

Comment: Is this the only rewrites you have ?? What happens for http://x-y.domain.com/

Comment: @Zimbabao That was the problem it redirected somehow to www.domain.com, but it is fixed now ill edit my question with the solution.